# fastest way to iterate ove linked hash map

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

What's the fastest way how to iterate over linked hash map, I need 100 last keys and first 20 keys. The size of this map will be in most cases over 500-1500, thanks

```
 LinkedHashMap<Integer, Float> doc_1 = service5.getMatchingValue(query);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Comment: If you are concerned about speed you shouldn't be iterating over a HashMap.  That is not what they are designed for.  Use a collection like List instead.  BTW I wouldn't use `float` or `Float` if you can help it.  `double` or `Double` has 9 digits more precision.

Comment: How often will you be replacing this map? Is it a retrieve once and iterate x times kind of operation?

Comment: you need [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) dude.

Comment: @user2511414 using a thread would be too overkill for this problem =\

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I've always found it strange that LinkedHashMap didn't provide useful iteration methods though, since it already maintains a doubly linked list. It could easily provide a reverse-order entry iterator, but doesn't. Any thought about that?

Comment: @JBNizet It appears to me that it could support ListIterator.  The problem is that LHM does give you any iterator. It is Collection which gives this and you would need to provide a special ListSet or ListCollection or something equally bizarre to return a ListIterator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza prove me I'm wrong buddy.

Comment: @user2511414 Using thread rarely speeds up simple tasks. esp if they have no level of inherent concurrency.  There is no reason to suspect threads would help so you would have to clarify what approach you propose and why. It is very easy to provide a slow solution if it is not optimal so this is not a proof.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I was thinking about something simpler, like `Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> reverseEntryIterator()` and `Iterator<K> reverseKeyIterator()`. You can iterate through the list in normal using `map.keySet().iterator()` and `map.entrySet().iterator()`, but there is no way to iterate in reverse order (AFAIK).

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed. Even reverseValuesIterator(), however ListIterator would be more powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you iterate over a HashMap you still would have O(n) runtime, as you would iterating over any other datastructure...

Iterating over a HashMap is just as time consuming as iterating over any DS.

If you only need specific entries of a hashmap, you might want to keep information on the required keys and only loop over those keys. Access to an element in a HashMap using its key is O(1) (or atleast amorized), accessing M entries (by their keys) using direct access results thus in O(M) runtime with O(M) << O(N).

You could perhaps keep the last 100 keys in a cache and just loop over (a copy) of the cache to have the best possible access (in terms of performance) in combination with your HashMap.